# In Magento 1.x How to add item to collection to the beginning?

Tags: magento-1, collection

It is possible to add element to the collection as the first element, similar to this method which adds element to the end?

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(15879);
$productCollection->addItem($product);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **DISCLAIMER:** Use the database for sorting purposes wherever possible. However, in some cases you might want to arrange items in a collection that are not stored in the database (yet), for example after dynamically adding items to the quote during `collectTotals()`. Then this approach will be useful.

Unfortunately not, `Varien_Data_Collection` is not very flexible in this respect. To reorder items in a collection you need to remove them and add them again in the desired order.

In your specific case:

```
// remove previous items, keep them in $items
$items = $productCollection->getItems();
foreach ($productCollection as $key => $item) {
    $collection->removeItemByKey($key);
}

// add new item
$productCollection->addItem($product);

// re-add $items
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $productCollection->addItem($item);
}
```

### Update: Performance

Since there are objections regarding performance, I did a little benchmark on a real product database. Note that loading a collection with 20K products is something you should never actually do but this is just to prove the point that iterating over the loaded arrays twice does not add a significant overhead:

**Test Script**

```
$startTime = microtime(true);
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->load();

printf("Loaded %d products. Time: %.2fs Memory: %s\n",
    $productCollection->count(), microtime(true)-$startTime, number_format(memory_get_usage(true)));

// remove previous items, keep them in $items
$items = $productCollection->getItems();
foreach ($productCollection as $key => $item) {
    $productCollection->removeItemByKey($key);
}

printf("Removed items. Time %.2fs Memory: %s\n",
    microtime(true)-$startTime, number_format(memory_get_usage(true)));

// add new item
$productCollection->addItem(Mage::getModel('catalog/product'));

// re-add $items
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $productCollection->addItem($item);
}

printf("Added items. Time %.2fs Memory: %s\n",
    microtime(true)-$startTime, number_format(memory_get_usage(true)));
```

**Output**

> Loaded 20761 products. Time: 3.70s Memory: 81,264,640
>
> Removed items. Time 3.92 Memory: 81,788,928
>
> Added items. Time 4.31 Memory: 81,788,928

And with a more realistic amount of 100 loaded products:

> Loaded 100 products. Time: 0.11s Memory: 10,223,616
>
> Removed items. Time 0.11s Memory: 10,223,616
>
> Added items. Time 0.12s Memory: 11,272,192

Comment: This is a terrible answer. You are doing not one but two foreachs over a collection before loading it. This will take forever for large collections and will decrease performance a lot.

Comment: I assumed, the collection is already loaded. Otherwise the question does not make much sense to me.

Comment: It clearly is and still, this idea adds TWO foreachs over a collection. This is not the case of loading inside a foreach, but going trough the entire collection twice before doing anything else will destroy any environment.

Comment: That's just not true. This is just a foreach over a PHP array, not even nested and no database queries are involved. Even if the loaded collection does contain all products (which would be terrible in the first place), it's lightning fast.

Comment: @mbalparda is right, manipulating collections using PHP is really very slow, always make the database server do the work using PHP only if there is absolutely no other option - large collections would absolutely grind to a halt with PHP.

Comment: @JonathanHussey I wholeheartily agree that you should let the database do the sorting gruntwork if possible. But since the question was without context and I see scenarios where this is a legit desire, I gave a solution.

Comment: That's fair enough, but it's better to assume we are talking about a larger rather than smaller collection - at some point someone with a larger collection is going to come across this question so the solutions should really be such that it's not going to kill the store for a good while.

Comment: @fschmengler  I'm added item like the above, but $this->getItems())->getSize() method gives the size of 0 but count($this->getItems()) gives the size 1 correctly  , is there any other important method that will fail if we add the item like the above

Comment: @mano `getSize()` triggers a `SELECT COUNT(*)` SQL query. Use `count()` instead of `getSize()` to count the items currently loaded in the collection object.

Comment: is there any other important method that will fail if we add the item like the above

Comment: Depends on your definition of "fail". Everything that triggers a new load will remove the item. Everything that uses `getSelect()` to make a new database query will ignore the item.

Answer (score 3):

A collection object has a standard array called `_items` which contains all the resulting models retrieved by the database query.  The `addItem()` method exists in class `Varien_Data_Collection` and if you look at it all it does is push an entry onto the end of the array and is subject to exactly the same behaviour as [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php):

```
public function addItem(Varien_Object $item)
{
    $itemId = $this->_getItemId($item);

    if (!is_null($itemId)) {
        if (isset($this->_items[$itemId])) {
            throw new Exception('Item ('.get_class($item).') with the same id "'.$item->getId().'" already exist');
        }
        $this->_items[$itemId] = $item;
    } else {
        $this->_addItem($item);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

And the `_addItem()` method is as follows:

```
protected function _addItem($item)
{
    $this->_items[] = $item;
    return $this;
}
```

Thus all that happens when calling the `addItem()` method is that a new entry is added to the end of the array using the id of the item you are adding if it exists as the key, otherwise using the next available auto increment key value (by not defining a key).

If you need to have the items ordered in a specific way, you should instead ensure your database query orders the results correctly, or pull all of the item from the collection object using `getItems()` and then order then using PHP.  By FAR the most efficient is to order them correctly in your database query, manipulating the results once pulled from the database via PHP is countless times slower.

Answer (score 1):

I do get any proper solution.Below solution may work:

Create new varien collection object:

```
 $collection- = new Varien_Data_Collection();


 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(15879);
```

**Assign the product add first element:**

```
 $collection->addItem($product);
```

**using loop assign rest of product:**

```
foreach($productCollection as $eachProd):
    $collection->addItem($eachProd); 
    endforeach;

$productCollection=$collection;
```

Comment: This method does not exist. There is only `getFirstItem()`

Comment: Although ok for small collections, iterating over an entire production collection using PHP is always going to be slow...

Comment: yes. i am agree  with you 100%

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task to add element to the collection as the first element.Below is the code i implemented and works perfectly for me.

```
$product = Mage::Model('catalog/product')->load(product_id);// product/element to add as first element

$collection = Mage::Model('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$collection->addAttributeToSelect.... // general code to select attributes

$collection->addAttributeToFilter.... // general code to apply filter

if($product && $product->getId()){ **// product to add as first element**

   $collection->addItem($product); // added product to collection

   $expr = new Zend_Db_Expr("`e`.`entity_id` = {$product->getId()} desc"); 

   $collection->getSelect()->order($expr); **// $product will be order by     DESC to set as first element**  

}

$collection->addAttributeToSort( 'price', 'asc'); // this sorting will apply on remaining elements in the collection.
```

#### Explanation

In the above code, `$product` is needed to add as first element, created a product collection `$collection`, added `$product` to that collection.

Using `$collection->getSelect()->order($expr);` forcefully sort position of `$product` to set as first position and rest of the elements will be order by `$collection->addAttributeToSort( 'price', 'asc');`

**Note** - It is must to call `$collection->getSelect()->order($expr);` before any sort by code.