# Magento add item to Product Collection but not showing up

Tags: product, collection, product-collection

I have a product Collection:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->getCollection()->setPageSize(10);
```

I want to add a product to that collection by using **addItem()** method:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(66);
$_productCollection->addItem($product);
```

I tried to dump my `$_productCollection` before and after using `addItem()` method but I get the same result.

What's wrong with that ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55227/how-to-add-item-to-magento-collection-to-the-beginning

Comment: I have followed that question but still cannot add item to product collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load the collection **before** adding items, but this will invalidate any filter you want to apply later

Try...

```
$_productCollection->load();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(66);
$_productCollection->addItem($product);
```